# How to add spaces between every character in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to create a function that inserts spaces between the characters of a string argument then return a new string which contains the same characters as the argument, separated by space characters.

E.g.

```
Hello
```

becomes

```
H e l l o
```

I'm a massive novice and I'm sure that this might seem like a no-brain'er to some people, but I just can't seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to turn the string into an array of single characters, and then the [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function to turn that back into a string where you specify a joining character (specifying space as the joining character):

```
function insertSpaces(aString) {
  return aString.split("").join(" ");
}
```

(Note that the parameter to `split()` is the character you want to split on so, e.g., you can use `split(",")` to break up a comma-separated list, but if you pass an empty string it just splits up every character.)

Comment: Thanks for this information. I think that I get the principle behind this. The aString.split splits up each character and then joins is back together with another space. 

That said... for some reason when I try to call the function - it isn't working... I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing wrong. 

to test the function, I'm using the following:

 <INPUT TYPE = "button" NAME = "insertSpacesButton"  VALUE ="Insert Spaces Between Characters"
   ONCLICK = "window.alert(insertSpaces(test));">

Comment: Ah. I got the answer just to let you know. I didn't include '' around my argument string insertSpaces('test')

Answer (score 2):

```
function insertSpaces(aString)
{
  return aString.split('').join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's quite easy... just call the replace method on the string as follow...

```
var str = "Hello";
console.info(str.replace(/\B/g, " ");
```

What am I doing here is replacing on non-word boundary which is inside the word. It's just reverse of the word boundary denoted by "\b", which is around the word; think it as if you are matching the border of the word.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative for a split and join solution could be:

```
'Hello'.replace(/(.(?!$))/g,'$1 '); //=> H e l l o
 //               ^all characters but the last
 //                          ^replace with found character + space
```

Or in a function:

```
function insertChr(str,chr) {
  chr = chr || ' '; //=> default is space
  return str.replace(/(.(?!$))/g,'$1'+chr);
}
//usage
insertChr('Hello');     //=> H e l l o
insertChr('Hello','-'); //=> H-e-l-l-o
```

or as a String prototype function:

```
String prototype.insertChr(chr){
  chr = chr || ' '; //=> default is space
  return this.replace(/(.(?!$))/g,'$1'+chr);
}
//usage
'Hello'.insertChr();    //=> H e l l o
'Hello'.insertChr('='); //=> H=e=l=l=o
```