# Add a space between characters in a String

Tags: javascript, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String Manipulation - Javascript -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371949/string-manipulation-javascript)

I have a string:

```
hello
```

and I want to add a space between each character to give:

```
h e l l o
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This may be a duplicate but it has a better answer than the other question, I think we should re-open this

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
"hello".split('').join(' '); // "h e l l o"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var text = "hello";
var betweenChars = ' '; // a space

alert(text.split('').join(betweenChars));
```

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
var hello = 'hello';
var test = '';

for(var i=0; i<hello.length; i++){
   test += hello.charAt(i) + ' ';     
}

alert(test);
```