# Implement a split functionality in javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone knows how can I implement this functionality in javascript?

```
'hello world'.spacify() -> 'h e l l o  w o r l d'
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to do that? What about CSS `letter-spacing`? In HTML you´ll have there only one space between words (2 or more white space characters are ignored).

Comment: Yes I need to do that.

Comment: Also answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437385/add-a-space-between-characters-in-a-string

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371949/string-manipulation-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'hello world'.split("").join(" ")` should do the job